# Email attachment is empty PHP (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently making a function in php (Codeigniter) where a xml-file is created. I store this file in a directory and want to mail it to someone.

The file is created and saved as it should, but when I send an email with the file attached, the attached file is empty/blank.

How can I fix this problem?

Here is my code:

```
    $doc->save("orders/$order_id.xml");

    //Mail XML-file
    $this->load->library('email');

    $file = 'orders/'.$order_id.'.xml';

    $this->email->from('noreply@xxxxx.nl', 'xxxx');
    $this->email->to('nick@xxxxxxx.nl');
    $this->email->attach($file);

    $this->email->subject('xxxxxx');
    $this->email->message('xxxxxxxx');

    $this->email->send();
```

SOLUTION:

In system/libraries/Email.php on line 725 change:

```
'content'   => chunk_split(base64_encode($file_content)),
```

to:

```
'content'   => "\r\n" . chunk_split(base64_encode($file_content)),
```

Comment: One thing is strange why don't you save to '$file'? Why generate file name 2 times? That is your first possible error.

Comment: Why is this `$doc->save("orders/$order_id.xml");` not `$doc->save("orders/{$order_id}.xml");` or `$doc->save("orders/" . $order_id . ".xml");`

Comment: Thx for your quick reply! I just found the solution..

In the email header there was missing a "\r\n". I fixed this by editing line 725 in system/libraries/Email.php from

this

'content' => chunk_split(base64_encode($file_content)),

to this

'content' => "\r\n" . chunk_split(base64_encode($file_content)),

Answer (score 0):

As a notice, that line 725 is in the 3.1.0 version. But you can search chunk_split(base64_encode($file_content)) in Email.php to update it in the later versions.